# Cloudflare CDN caching and google analytics doubts?

Tags: javascript, caching, google-analytics, cdn, cloudflare

I started using cloudflare CDN today. I am facing a few issues related to the service. I recently uploaded prism.js on my website but after a few hours decide to replace it with another version of prism.js. Now, the issue is that on some servers it loads new version of prism.js and on other the old version. I tested it using webpagetest.org. I already clicked on purge cache but that did not resolve the issue.
1. Is there someway to make sure that changes to my own .js and .css files appear quickly. 2. If I have already included google analytics code should I remove it if I am using cloud flare analytics app. What difference does it make? 3. How does cloudflare help in reducing bandwidth usage and are there any bandwidth restrictions? 4. I have my webpages with .php extension So they are not going to be cached are they?

Don't mark this question as not related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"1. Is there someway to make sure that changes to my own .js and .css files appear quickly."

Go to Development Mode or purge file/full cache (you might have to do a hard refresh on your browser to make the changes show immediately as well).

"2. If I have already included google analytics code should I remove it if I am using cloud flare analytics app."

" 4. I have my webpages with .php extension So they are not going to be cached are they?"
We do not cache php by default. [Static content we cache by default](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Which-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-)

Are you doing any customization within Google Analytics relative to tracking? If yes, then you should use Google's default way of installing their codes to your site. The app integration we have will only handle regular GA setups.

"How does cloudflare help in reducing bandwidth usage and are there any bandwidth restrictions?
By caching static content & also by filtering potentially malicious traffic. We do not have any bandwidth restrictions, but that doesn't mean your hosting provider doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Cloudflare for a number of clients for a while now and it works amazingly well for the hight traffic websites. For the highest traffic client, it has cut 5-8s load time off our pages on both desktop and mobile. Please note that some of the features discussed below do require paid plans.

1. The best way to avoid this is to set up page rules. By [setting a page rule](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-) that doesn't cache the problem .js and .css files, they should always be served from your servers, not Cloudflares. I have had this exact problem and page rules solved the problem.
2. Cloudflares GA app only supports standard GA code, so if you have made any customisations, you should keep it in the head of your pages. [You should not use both the Cloudflare GA app and GA code](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172616-Does-CloudFlare-affect-Google-Analytics-) in your pages as it will fire the GA code twice and the analytics will read too high.
3. Depending on the level of caching that you choose (on a paid plan), Cloudlare can cache just your static content or all of your content. It can store your content at lots of different physical locations and serve it from the location closest to your request (paid plan). It also serves just static HTML from their servers (not yours), saving your bandwidth. This can mean less work is needed to be done by the browser too increasing speed. As far as I can see there are no bandwidth restrictions. On some sites, I see a bandwidth saving of 90%. That is a huge cost saving on server resources on a high traffic site.
4. PHP is not cached by default. Again you can change the level of caching, depending on your needs (paid plan). Everything can be cached so no recalculations are done when the page is served (only really useful for static HTML, but also possible for PHP with query strings), or you can choose from a few different levels of caching depending on your needs. The standard caching only really caches static content